# What does " in accounts of" mean in this context? And i don't understand the sentence

Tags: meaning

He even told Rieux that it was really a great improvement on the deathcarts driven by Negroes of which one reads **in accounts of** former visitations of this sort.

Answer (score 1):

> ... of which one reads in accounts of former visitations of this sort.

**Paraphrase**

... of which one reads in stories about former visitations of this sort.

---

> **account** /əˈkaʊnt/ noun
>
> 1. a report or description of an event or experience: "a detailed account of what has been achieved" synonyms description, report,
>    version, story, narration, ... more

Oxford Dictionaries
https://uk.search.yahoo.com/search?fr=mcafee&type=E211GB0G0&p=account+definition

---

**Paraphrase of the whole sentence**

> He even told Rieux that it was really a great improvement on the
> deathcarts driven by Negroes of which one reads in accounts of former
> visitations of this sort.

He even told Rieux that it (i.e. something mentioned previously) was really a great improvement on the deathcarts (which were driven by Negroes) that you can  read about in stories concerning visitations (presumably occurrences of plague) of this sort.

i.e. you can read about the deathcarts.

Comment: Thank you very much!!

Comment: You're welcome. I may have added a bit since you commented.